# How do I distribute the contents of one array into another equally (when the array to be merged is smaller)?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

PHP. I have two arrays: planets and asteroids. I have more asteroids than I have planets. How do I merge the two arrays so that the asteroids are as evenly distributed among the planets as possible?

Currently I have a zip merge going on, but I end up with a ton of asteroids at the bottom of the array. Ideally I'd like p - a - p - a - p - a but I'd prefer p - a - a - p - a - a - p when there are too many asteroids to distribute evenly.

Also their order is important so even if I distribute three asteroids to every planet they have to stay in the order they were in before they were merged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the length of both arrays by calling sizeof on them. Use the result of a / p (where a is the length of the asteroids array and p is the length of the planets array) as the number of asteroids per planet. If a does not divide equally into p then you would have to floor the result and have perhaps one left over.
Then you can create a new array to hold the result, loop through the planets array, adding one planet followed by x asteroids to your new array.

Comment: How do I determine how many asteroids to distribute though when you say "followed by x asteroids"?

Comment: sizeof($asteroids) / sizeof($planets) (assuming those are the actual names given to your arrays) = number of asteroids per planet. You'll need to floor it in the case where asteroids doesn't divide into planets equally.

Comment: Thank you. Ultimately I didn't have to do the distribution and went a different way, but hopefully your comments will be useful to people in the future.